# Spring AOP proxy and interface implementation

Tags: spring, proxy, spring-aop

I'm trying to understand Spring proxy mechanism and I have problem with one thing.
I have Interface:

```
public interface MyInterface{
  void myMethod();
}
```

and implementing class:

```
@Component
public class MyBean implements MyInterface{
  @Override
  public void myMethod(){
    //do something
  }
}
```

Now I create Aspect, for example:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LogAspect {
    @Before("execution(public * *(..))")
    public void logBefore() {
        System.out.println("Before aspect");
    }
}
```

And I have simple starter class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class SpringAopApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
                SpringAopApplication.class);

        MyBean bean = ctx.getBean(MyBean.class);
//      MyInterface bean = ctx.getBean(MyInterface.class); //works
        bean.myMethod();

        ctx.close();
    }
}
```

According to the Spring docs we can read:

> If the target object to be proxied implements at least one interface
>   then a JDK dynamic proxy will be used. All of the interfaces
>   implemented by the target type will be proxied. If the target object
>   does not implement any interfaces then a CGLIB proxy will be created.

But I got an error *No qualifying bean of type [MyBean] is defined*. It works only when I enable CGLib proxying by `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)`.
Can someone explain what I am missing here? Why MyBean is not discovered when using AOP? `ctx.getBean(MyInterface.class)` works, but I can't imagine the situation with many implementations of such interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The target object to be proxied (MyBean) implements at least one interface (MyInterface), so a JDK proxy is used.
This proxy implements MyInterface, but is NOT an instance of MyBean.
Thats why

```
MyInterface bean = ctx.getBean(MyInterface.class);
```

works and

```
MyBean bean = ctx.getBean(MyBean.class);
```

not.

CGLib proxies are created by subclassing the target object, so the bean created is a subclass of MyBean  and implements MyInterface.
In this case also

```
MyBean bean = ctx.getBean(MyBean.class);
```

works.

> ...but I can't imagine the situation with many implementations of such interface.

The only reason for MyInterface could be, to allow spring to create a JDK proxy, so there is no need to have many implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Because if you check up your bean class you'll find com.sun.proxy.$Proxy21 (or something similar) instead, which wraps your method. They are incompatible types even they have the same interface.
For example:

```
public interface AnInterface {
   void func();
}

public class Bb implements AnInterface{
   @Override
   public void func() {
      System.out.println("bb");
   }
}

public class Cc implements AnInterface{
@Override
   public void func() {
      System.out.println("cc");
   }
}
```

So when you call

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Bb b = new Bb();
    Cc c=b; // Error
    AnInterface c=b; // Ok
}
```